# My vue application is not routing just showing the following url in the browser http://localhost:8080/#/

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

i created 2 view one login.vue and register.vue and i impoetred them in the index.js inside the router folder but when i try to route to certain paden all the route show a # like the pages dont exist

my index .js inside the router folder

```
import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory } from 'vue-router'

import Login from '../views/Login.vue'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import Register from '../views/Register.vue'


const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/register',
    name: 'Register',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ 
    '../views/Register.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ 
    '../views/Login.vue')
   },
 ]

 
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(),
  routes
})

export default router
```

Comment: Do you have errors in the browser console?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: Home is not defined
    at eval (index.js?5aa4:10:1)
    at ./src/router/index.js (app.js:85:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:266:33)
    at fn (app.js:521:21)
    at eval (main.js:4:65)
    at ./src/main.js (app.js:74:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:266:33)
    at app.js:1446:109
    at __webpack_require__.O (app.js:312:23)
    at app.js:1447:53

Comment: @patso please [edit] your post to include the full error traceback, properly formatted

Comment: is the error even still relevant?  the original post was missing `import Home` which would explain the error but now the post has been edited to include the import (but not the error).  is there any new error?  did fixing the error fix the original problem? I'm not sure what is relevant and what is not anymore.